# Debian packaging: mk-build-deps cannot install particular version of Build-Depends packages

Tags: debian, repository, packaging, deb

I need to build a project which depends on the particular version of third-party library:

```
➜  cat debian/control 
Source: libhole-cpp
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Vitaly Isaev <isaev@embarce.ro>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), cmake, 
    flatbuffers (= 1.2.0-1),
    libboost-dev,
    libboost-system-dev,
    catch
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
```

However, there are several `flatbuffers` packages in our repo, including the newer ones:

```
➜  apt-cache policy flatbuffers
flatbuffers:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.4.0-17
  Version table:
     1.4.0-17 500
        500 http://repo12.mailbuild-2.embarce.ro xenial/local amd64 Packages
     1.2.0-1 500
        500 http://repo12.mailbuild-2.embarce.ro xenial/local amd64 Packages
```

Under this conditions `mk-build-deps` refuses to install the desired version of a package:

```
➜  sudo mk-build-deps --install debian/control
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_install
dh_installdocs
dh_installchangelogs
dh_compress
dh_fixperms
dh_installdeb
dh_gencontrol
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package 'libhole-cpp-build-deps' in '../libhole-cpp-build-deps_1.0.1ubuntu1_all.deb'.

The package has been created.
Attention, the package has been created in the current directory,
not in ".." as indicated by the message above!
Selecting previously unselected package libhole-cpp-build-deps.
(Reading database ... 68846 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libhole-cpp-build-deps_1.0.1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhole-cpp-build-deps (1.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies...Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) libhole-cpp-build-deps [ amd64 ] < 1.0.1ubuntu1 > ( devel )
Broken libhole-cpp-build-deps:amd64 Depends on flatbuffers [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.4.0-17 > ( devel ) (= 1.2.0-1)
  Considering flatbuffers:amd64 0 as a solution to libhole-cpp-build-deps:amd64 -2
  Removing libhole-cpp-build-deps:amd64 rather than change flatbuffers:amd64
Done
 Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libhole-cpp-build-deps
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 9216 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 68850 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libhole-cpp-build-deps (1.0.1ubuntu1) ...
mk-build-deps: Unable to install libhole-cpp-build-deps at /usr/bin/mk-build-deps line 402.
mk-build-deps: Unable to install all build-dep packages
➜  libhole-cpp git:(v12) ✗ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Could anyone please clarify what's wrong with my build toolchain? The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It's generally helpful to have the complete code, including the Debian packaging, available. Can you post a link for that?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Sorry, can't do it since this is a proprietary software

Comment: Are you trying to install `flatbuffers  1.2` ?

Comment: @GAD3R I really do. I've specified this version in ````debian/control````

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tldr;

Delegate to the `aspcud` solver via `apt-cudf-get`:

```
mk-build-deps \
    --install \
    --remove \
    --tool \
    'apt-cudf-get --solver aspcud -o APT::Get::Assume-Yes=1 -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=0 -o APT::Install-Recommends=0' \
    debian/control
```

### Explanation

This solution differs from [that of Johannes Schauer](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/08/msg00446.html) in that...

- it uses `apt-cudf-get` instead of `apt-get`
- it omits the following options (which didn't work in my testing):

  - `-o APT::Solver::Strict-Pinning=false`
  - `-o APT::Solver::aspcud::Preferences="-new,-removed,-changed"`
- it adds the following options:

  - `-o APT::Get::Assume-Yes=1` (to install packages non-interactively)
  - `-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=1` (`mk-build-deps --tool` default)
  - `-o APT::Install-Recommends=0` (`mk-build-deps --tool` default)

### References:

- debian-devel mailing list thread index for "mk-build-deps cannot install particular version of Build-Depends packages": https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/08/threads.html#00442

  - Vitaly Isaev starting the thread: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/08/msg00442.html
  - Johannes Schauer, proposing aspcud: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/08/msg00446.html
- aspcud

  - homepage: https://potassco.org/aspcud/
  - source code repository: https://github.com/potassco/aspcud
- `apt-cudf` Debian package: https://packages.debian.org/stable/apt-cudf
- `apt-cudf` Debian man page: https://manpages.debian.org/stable/apt-cudf/apt-cudf-get.8.html
- `apt-cudf-get` Debian man page: https://manpages.debian.org/stable/apt-cudf/apt-cudf.1.html
- `mk-build-deps` Debian man page: https://manpages.debian.org/stable/devscripts/mk-build-deps.1.html